# BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck

Tags: kernel, virtualization, openstack, kvm-virtualization

I am running some SD-WAN applications like SDN switching, routing etc.., in a GUEST node (Ubuntu Linux 14.04 VM) which is Hosted in an Compute node of **Openstack environment**.

### Host Node details:

```
root@host-node:/var/log/nova# uname -r
4.4.0-71-generic

root@host-node:/var/log/nova# dpkg -l | egrep -i 'qemu|kvm|libvirt'
ii ipxe-qemu 1.0.0+git-20150424.a25a16d-1ubuntu1 all PXE boot firmware - ROM images for qemu
ii libvirt-bin 1.3.1-1ubuntu10.15 amd64 programs for the libvirt library
ii libvirt0:amd64 1.3.1-1ubuntu10.15 amd64 library for interfacing with different virtualization systems
ii python-libvirt 1.3.1-1ubuntu1 amd64 libvirt Python bindings
ii qemu 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14 amd64 fast processor emulator
ii qemu-block-extra:amd64 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 extra block backend modules for qemu-system and qemu-utils
ii qemu-slof 20151103+dfsg-1ubuntu1 all Slimline Open Firmware – QEMU PowerPC version
ii qemu-system 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries
ii qemu-system-arm 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries (arm)
ii qemu-system-common 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries (common files)
ii qemu-system-mips 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries (mips)
ii qemu-system-misc 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries (miscelaneous)
ii qemu-system-ppc 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries (ppc)
ii qemu-system-sparc 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries (sparc)
ii qemu-system-x86 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU full system emulation binaries (x86)
ii qemu-user 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.14 amd64 QEMU user mode emulation binaries
ii qemu-utils 1:2.5+dfsg-5ubuntu10.16 amd64 QEMU utilities
CPU
processor : 47
vendor_id : GenuineIntel
cpu family : 6
model : 63
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2690 v3 @ 2.60GHz
stepping : 2
microcode : 0x38
cpu MHz : 2902.046
cache size : 30720 KB
physical id : 1
siblings : 24
core id : 13
cpu cores : 12
apicid : 59
initial apicid : 59
fpu : yes
fpu_exception : yes
cpuid level : 15
wp : yes
flags : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm xsaveopt cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs :
bogomips : 5194.87
clflush size : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

root@host-node:/var/log/nova# free -m
total used free shared buff/cache available
Mem: 773931 186967 490462 4070 96502 576184
Swap: 0 0 0
```

Suddenly the GUEST node (where the SDN application running) is not reachable by any means (Not pinging, NO SSH). 
Even in the Openstack Horizon Dashboard console is freezed.

**Only remedy is to reboot (Hard Reboot) the GUEST node and after that it comes UP and running without any issues.**

Below are the console logs posted.

```
[1263400.052002] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#0 stuck for 22s! [XXXX:1722]
[1263436.850392] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#12 stuck for 31s! [python:2059]
[1263436.855480] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 57s! [sleep:18861]
[1263436.852476] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#8 stuck for 38s! [monit:1864]
[1263436.850131] [sched_delayed] sched: RT throttling activated
[1263436.855565] Modules linked in:
[1263436.850392] Modules linked in:
[1263436.855924] 
[1263436.855924] CPU: 1 PID: 18861 Comm: sleep Tainted: G           OE 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[1263436.852476] CPU: 8 PID: 1864 Comm: monit Tainted: G           OE 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[1263436.850392] CPU: 12 PID: 2059 Comm: python Tainted: G           OE 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu
[1263436.855924] Hardware name: OpenStack Foundation OpenStack Nova, BIOS Ubuntu-1.8.2-1ubuntu1 04/01/2014
[1263436.852476] Hardware name: OpenStack Foundation OpenStack Nova, BIOS Ubuntu-1.8.2-1ubuntu1 04/01/2014
[1263436.850392] Hardware name: OpenStack Foundation OpenStack Nova, BIOS Ubuntu-1.8.2-1ubuntu1 04/01/2014
[1263436.855924] task: ffff88055f497010 ti: ffff88055bc68000 task.ti: ffff88055bc68000
[1263436.852476] task: ffff880812045180 ti: ffff8800bb840000 task.ti: ffff8800bb840000
[1263436.850392] task: ffff8800bb281460 ti: ffff880811b94000 task.ti: ffff880811b94000
[1263436.852476] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff81776676>] 
[1263436.850392] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff811b9275>]
```

**GUEST node details:**

```
 uname -a
Linux Guest-node 3.16.0-77-generic #99~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 28 19:17:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

 uname -r
3.16.0-77-generic
```

Note: When the GUEST node freezed, HOST Compute in Openstack environment is showing 100% CPU usage in all the 16 cores.

```
Threads:  19 total,  16 running,   3 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.8 us,  6.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 89.5 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 79250592+total, 55210470+free, 18854126+used, 51860008 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 59347756+avail Mem 

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                       
20666 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 99.9  1.8  20126:42 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20654 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20123:30 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20655 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20127:04 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20656 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20127:04 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20657 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20127:00 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20658 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20126:57 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20659 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20126:54 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20660 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20126:58 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20661 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20126:54 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20662 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20127:37 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20663 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20128:59 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20664 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20128:48 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20665 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20127:01 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20667 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20128:41 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20668 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20127:04 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20669 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 R 93.8  1.8  20006:54 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20597 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 S  0.0  1.8   4:38.56 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20647 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 S  0.0  1.8   0:00.03 qemu-system-x86                                                                                                               
20671 libvirt+  20   0 37.586g 0.013t  26076 S  0.0  1.8   0:01.83 qemu-system-x86
```

Observation:

Kernel Version of HOST Compute Node:
root@host-node:/var/log/nova# uname -r
4.4.0-71-generic

So it is not exactly clear that whether the above issue is linked to the Linux Kernel version.

**Workaround 1**
Below link is close to the reported issue and will there be any issue in implementing the same in Virtual environment like Openstack cloud infrastructure.

https://customerhelp.co.za/linux/ubuntu/fix-ubuntu-bug-soft-lockup-cpu-stuck-vmware-server.html

Note: We implemented the above solution and still the issue stuck again.

**Workaround 2** Based on some more analysis, below kernel version of Ubuntu has known issues for soft lockup issue.

```
roothost-node:/var/log/nova# uname -r 
4.4.0-71-generic
```

***Appreciate if someone could help with any information for the above reported issue. 
Thanks.***

Comment: I'm a bit confused. When you say you implemented the kernel flags `pci=noacpi acpi=off noapic` in Workaround 1 did you update grub and reboot? Regarding Workaround 2, did you attempt to boot from a previous kernel? Did you by any chance attempt both booting a previous kernel and editing the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` entry as described in Workaround 1? Please [edit] your post to clarify these points. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Hello Elder, Thanks for the reply. After updating the Workaround 1, we did fix-grub and then restarted to get it effected.we have properly implemented the workaround 1 and the frequency of occurring reduced but never stopped. For the Workaround 2 i have not upgraded to latest kernel unless that is confirmed to be the root cause of the issue.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion you may be experiencing. I asked whether you had tried applying to a previous kernel, not the latest. Please read [my previous comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990275/bug-soft-lockup-cpu0-stuck?noredirect=1#comment1596386_990275) again.

Comment: Hello Elder, We did not attempt to upgrade / downgrade the kernel version unless if this is to be confirmed or near confirmed to be an kernel issue.

Comment: Currently I do plan to upgrade to kernel version, but looking other alternatives too.

Comment: So the answer to my question is no, you did not try choosing a previous kernel from the grub menu and editing the kernel parameters.